# How to use while read line with tail -n

Tags: bash, csv, while-loop, tail

**Problem:** I have a CSV dump file - with excess of 250,000 lines. When I use `while read` - it takes a while (no pun intended). I would like to go back to the last 10,000 lines to do what I need to do instead of the 250,000 lines.

**Code Snippet:** My current code is this:

```
IFS=","
while read line
do

    awk_var=`echo "$line" | awk -F" " '{print $0}'`

    var_array=($awk_var)

    read -a var_array <<< "${awk_var}"

    echo "${var_array[1]}"


done </some_directory/directory/file_in_question.csv
```

**Question:** How can I use `tail -n10000` with `while read line` when reading the `file_in_question.csv` with a bash script?

Comment: `{print $0}` is the same as `{print}` to awk which is the same as not using awk at all. What were you trying to do there? And the time here is likely from the 250,000 calls to `awk` (once per-loop). Avoid those if you can.

Comment: @EtanReisner Well the first parameter is a Unix Timestamp in seconds, so, I calculate a boundary (two dates/timestamps), and extract the data inbetween the aforementioned boundary. What would be an alternative to do something like this that could make my code faster?

Comment: My point was that `awk_var=$(echo "$line" | awk -F " " '{print $0}')` is exactly the same as `awk_var=$(echo "$line")` which is exactly the same as `awk_var=$line` which is the same as just using `$line` in the first place only with two fewer external commands, one less sub-shell and a few fewer lines of code. Also `var_array=($awk_var)` is wrong and you overwrite `awk_var` with the `read` a line later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace:

```
done </some_directory/directory/file_in_question.csv
```

with:

```
done < <(tail -n10000 /some_directory/directory/file_in_question.csv)
```

The `<(...)` construct is called *process substitution*.  It creates a file-like object that bash can read from.  Thus, this replaces reading from `some_directory/directory/file_in_question.csv` directly with reading from `tail -n10000 /some_directory/directory/file_in_question.csv`.

Using process substitution like this allows you to keep your `while` loop in the main shell, not a subshell.  Because of this, variables that you create in the `while` loop will retain their value after the loop exits.

#### Speeding up the original code

The code as shown prints the second column of a CSV file.  If that is all that the code is supposed to do, then it can be replaced with:

```
awk -F, '{print $2}' /some_directory/directory/file_in_question.csv
```

Comment: Thanks John, Just a quick question - Is using `MyVar=$(some_command)` _ie GetTodaysDate=$(date +%F)_ also considered _process substitution_?

Comment: @3kstc No, that is _command substitution_.  The difference is that _command_ substitution captures the stdout of a process while  _process_ substitution makes a file-like object.

Comment: Oh, that's correct, my apologies - I got my substitutions mixed up :S !

Comment: How can I exit from while read in this case?


Edit: nvm, just add "break" command inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
IFS=","
tail /var/log/httpd/error_log | while read foo bar
do
    echo $foo
done
```

I recommend you do the splitting in bash with `read`, instead of calling `awk` inefficiently there. Obviously rewriting the whole thing as an awk script will be faster than shell, but awk is harder less common language.

Answer (score 0):

Or this one.

```
while : 
do read l || { sleep 1 ; continue; }
   echo "==> $l"
done < /var/log/httpd/error_log
```