# Shell read from files with tail

Tags: bash, shell, sh, process-substitution

I am currently trying to read from files with shell. However, I met one sytax issue. My code is below:

```
while read -r line;do
    echo $line
done < <(tail -n +2 /pathToTheFile | cut -f5,6,7,8 | sort | uniq )
```

However, it returns me error `syntax error near unexpected token`('`

I tried with following [How to use while read line with tail -n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33535558/how-to-use-while-read-line-with-tail-n) but still cannot see the error.

The tail command works properly.

Any help will be apprepricated.

Comment: process substitution isn't support by posix shell `/bin/sh`. It is a feature specific to bash (and other). Are you running this in `/bin/bash`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) isn't support by the posix shell /bin/sh. It is a feature specific to bash (and other non posix shells). Are you running this in /bin/bash?

Anyhow, the process substitution isn't needed here, you could simple use a pipe, like this:

```
tail -n +2 /pathToTheFile | cut -f5,6,7,8 | sort -u | while read -r line ; do
    echo "${line}"
done
```

Comment: Yeah...u r right....did not realise this until you mendtioned...thx for the help...

Answer (score 1):

Your interpreter must be `#!/bin/bash` not `#!/bin/sh` and/or you must run the script with `bash scriptname` instead of `sh scriptname`.

**Why?**

POSIX shell doesn't provide *process-substitution*. Process substitution (e.g. `< <(...)`) is a bashism and not available in POSIX shell. So the error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token('
```

Is telling you that once the script gets to your `done` statement and attempts to find the file being redirected to the loop it finds `'('` and chokes. (that also tells us you are invoking your script with POSIX shell instead of bash -- and now you know why)